# Xcode organizer crash [Swift runtime failure: Index out of range]

Tags: arrays, swift

I've checked the crash logs in Xcode's Organizer > App > Reports > Crashes section and found this problem, but I don't understand why I am getting an Index out of range error when I know for sure that I am interating within the bounds of the array.
Here is my code

```
struct BannerView: View {
    @State private var currentPage = 0
    @State private var timer: Timer? = nil

    var list: [Banner] = []
    var duration: Double = 3.0

    func nextPage() -> Void {
        if self.currentPage == self.list.count - 1 {
            self.currentPage = 0
        } else {
            self.currentPage += 1
        }
    }
    
    func restLoop() -> Void {
        if self.timer == nil && self.duration > 0 {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration, repeats: true) { timer in
                nextPage()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            PageViewController(
                pages: self.list.map { banner in
                    BannerCard(banner: banner)
                },
                currentPage: $currentPage,
                onChange: {
                    self.timer?.invalidate()
                    self.timer = nil
                    self.restLoop()
                })
            PageControl(numberOfPages: list.count, currentPage: $currentPage)
                .frame(width: CGFloat(list.count * 18))
        }
        .onAppear() {
            restLoop()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct PageViewController<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pages: [Page]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int
    var onChange: () -> Void

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            parent = pageViewController
            controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return controllers.last
            }
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == controllers.count {
                return controllers.first
            }
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
            transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            
            if completed,
               let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
               let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                parent.currentPage = index
                parent.onChange()
            }
                
        }
    }

}
```

Crash Log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001028bf3a8
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [3966]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf3a8 Swift runtime failure: Index out of range + 0 (<compiler-generated>:0)
1   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf3a8 specialized Array._checkSubscript(_:wasNativeTypeChecked:) + 4 (<compiler-generated>:0)
2   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf3a8 specialized Array.subscript.getter + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
3   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf3a8 PageViewController.updateUIViewController(_:context:) + 372
4   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf2e4 PageViewController.updateUIViewController(_:context:) + 176
5   qdnft                           0x00000001028bf930 protocol witness for UIViewControllerRepresentable.updateUIViewController(_:context:) in conformance PageViewController<A> + 40 (<compiler-generated>:0)
6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001d846a8d8 PlatformViewControllerRepresentableAdaptor.updateViewProvider(_:context:) + 396 (PlatformViewControllerRepresentableAdaptor.swift:33)
```

Clearly, I am missing something here? Anyone care to shed some light on this? I don't know why code as innocuous as this would cause any problems.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your `list`  is empty, then you can't access to empty array.

I think if you populate your list with at least one `Banner` it don't crash:

```
var list: [Banner] = [Banner()]
```

In order to better understand, if you run this script:

```
var a = [2] // not empty
print(a[0])
```

print `2` correctly; but if you run this:

```
var a = [Int]() // empty
print(a[0])
```

or this:

```
var a: [Int] = [] // empty
print(a[0])
```

crash.